# Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/app/views"

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, ejs

Getting this error every time I try to deploy app to heroku. Works completely fine when run on local host: 3000

```
2022-11-13T14:46:11.815962+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2022-11-13T14:46:15.619107+00:00 app[web.1]: Server has started
2022-11-13T14:46:15.861854+00:00 app[web.1]: DB connected successfully
2022-11-13T14:46:16.018081+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-13T14:52:47.472985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=stark-lowlands-39210.herokuapp.com request_id=ef33e137-00ea-48d8-be4f-05b0c4fa505a fwd="12.205.212.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=27ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477306+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/app/views"
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477309+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477309+00:00 app[web.1]: at ServerResponse.render (/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477311+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/app.js:20:9
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477312+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477312+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477313+00:00 app[web.1]: at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477313+00:00 app[web.1]: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477314+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477315+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
2022-11-13T14:52:47.477315+00:00 app[web.1]: at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
```

I'm including my app.js, server.js, and folder hierarchy below:

[image: Folder/file Structure]

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const mongoose  = require("mongoose");
const https = require("https");
// const File = require("./model/fileSchema");
const multer = require("multer");
const http = require('http');

const app = express();

// Set up code
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname + "/views"));
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
});
```

server.js

```
const app = require("./app");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const http = require('http');
const https = require("https");
const path = require("path");

process.on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
  console.log("UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION, APP SHUTTING NOW!!");
  console.log(err.message, err.name);
  process.exit(1);
});

const DB = "mongodb+srv://boepartners:missyangus123@cluster0.dm8gvgf.mongodb.net/BOE";

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    autoIndex: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("DB connected successfully");
  });

  let port = process.env.PORT;
  if (port == null || port == "") {
    port = 3000;
  }

  app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log("Server has started");
  });
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm expecting the index.ejs file to be rendered properly when deploying to heroku.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

To render template files, set the following application setting properties in app.js.

- views, the directory where the template files are located. Eg: app.set('views', './views'). This defaults to the views directory in the application root directory.
- view engine, the template engine to use. For example, to use the ejs template engine: app.set('view engine', 'ejs').

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');
```

As per your directory, `app.js` and `views` are in same level. So, change the property to this `app.set('views', 'views')`. This would work.
And also change the following properting

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Comment: Hey I changed to that and got this Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "views"